# It is recommended use a large object where keys are string Codes for better access instead array that needs iterations?

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I have a data structure like this

```
   {
       "stores": [
         { code: 'A7-22', name: 'market'},
         { code: 'A8-22', name: 'drugstore'},
         ... 250 items
       ]
   }
```

Then in the code I search a store using:

```
const code = 'A7-22';
const store = data.stores.find(store => store.code === code)
```

But I think that could be a good idea to change the data structure to

```
   {
       "stores": {
         'A7-22': {name: 'market'},
         'A8-22': { name: 'drugstore'},
         ... 250 items
       ]
   }
```

and now the code it is more easy to handle:

```
const code = 'A7-22';
const store = data.stores[code]
```

Now, consider that this code is running in a backend artifact with high traffic and in the future, the store could be > 10.000.

The question is:
**There are some performance issues related to this code if I take the option 2 using a large object with "key value strategy"?**

Comment: No, your idea is quite sound. It reduces complexity from `O(n)` to `O(1)`. Go for it.

Comment: Worth noting that 10,000 is a big number but from array size point of view in modern javascript environments isn't a lot at all

Comment: I would like to point that if performance is not a issue (and 10k elements does not sounds  like a problem), you should use the right data structure based on what's more "clear". For example, if the order of some data matters, I would probably choose an array-like structure, or if choosing an array makes the code simpler to follow.
In your case, I would choose an object. Not for performance, but for clarity.

Comment: Is there just a "name"?  If so, shrink it further: `stores: {
         'A7-22':  'market',
         'A8-22':  'drugstore', ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely the second option is faster. Here is the challenge for two cases:

```js
var code = 'A7-22', store={};

var data = {
    "stores": [
     { code: 'A8-22', name: 'drugstore'},
    ]
};

for(var i=1; i<10000; i++) { 
    data.stores.push({ code: 'x'+i, name: 'v'+i}); 
}
data.stores.push({ code: 'A7-22', name: 'market'});
   

var t1 = new Date();
for(var i=1; i<1000; i++) { 
    store = data.stores.find(store => store.code === code);
}
var t2 = new Date();
var dt = (t2.getTime() - t1.getTime());

   
document.write("<p> <b>Option 1 (using find):</b> " + code + ": " + store.name + ',  dt: '+ dt + " msec</p>");

// -------------------

var data2 = {
    "stores": {
     'A8-22': {name: 'drugstore'}
    }
};

for(var i=1; i<10000; i++) { 
    data2.stores['x'+i] = {name: 'v'+i}; 
}
data2.stores['A7-22'] = { name: 'market'};
   

var t1 = new Date();
for(var i=1; i<1000; i++) { 
    store = data2.stores[code]
}
var t2 = new Date();
var dt = (t2.getTime() - t1.getTime());


document.write("<p> <b>Option 2 (using array index):</b> " + code + ": " + store.name + ',  dt: '+ dt + "msec</p>");
```

Note that the high traffic you mentioned is not important here as this code is run in clients.